# Postfix to redirect non example.com email

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, email

I am wanting to setup postfix to redirect all outbound email from the server that is "not" address to @example.com to go to a mailing list that i have created to capture all non example.com emails. The server that this runs on is designed to send out email reports to external people but I need a way to test/review these emails.

For example.

user@gmail.com => mailinglist@example.com
* => maillinglist@example.com

But i still need emails that are address to my users to be send as normal.
user1@example.com -> user1@example.com

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

For `local` deliveries, try [`luser_relay`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#luser_relay).

In a [`virtual_alias` or `virtual_mailbox`](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) setup, add an entry for `@example.com` pointing to the mailing list.